# Angularjs return $location url without parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My application have a url like this: "`http://host:port/mySystem?x.system`"

The *x.system* had to be added because a legacy application need this stuff on all url's, and my application depends on this legacy application.

My problem is that i need the pure url of the system like this :  "`http://host:port/mySystem`", but when i use $location.absUrl() it returns : "`http://host:port/mySystem?x.system`"

There's a way to get the url with $location (or another service on angular), without the parameters ?

Comment: try window.location instead

Comment: location.host + location.port() + location.path, something like this

Comment: @BiAiB, using Angular, this is a bad habit to use window.location

Comment: `window.location` is provided by Angular as `$location`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$location` to pull out whatever you need to build a URL.  [Here is a Plunker from the official docs](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) that shows all the different parts.  You probably want something like this:

```
function buildBaseUrl() {
  return $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + ':' + $location.port() + $location.path()
}
```